# BigQuery how to create a query regex with special character ' | ' ? in standard sql

Tags: google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, I would like please your help to create this query in regex with this special character ' | ' or an equivalent in standard sql ?
The idea is to use a regex instead of having several fields ("login", "Unknown", "registration", "login", "start", "null") for this field
hit.eventInfo.eventCategory

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
visitNumber,
visitStartTime,
date,
totals.visits,
totals.hits,
totals.pageviews,
totals.timeOnSite,
hit.hitNumber,
hit.page.pagePath,
hit.page.hostname,
hit.page.pageTitle,
hit.eventInfo.eventCategory,
hit.eventInfo.eventAction,
hit.eventInfo.eventLabel,
cd.index,
cd.value
FROM
[bqdatasetnumber.ga_sessions_*],
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180905'
AND '20180911'
AND customDimensions.value != "null"
AND hit.eventInfo.eventCategory != "login"
AND hit.eventInfo.eventCategory != "null"
AND hit.eventInfo.eventCategory != "Unknown"
AND hit.eventInfo.eventCategory != "registration"
AND hit.eventInfo.eventAction != "start"
```

Thank for your help & tips

Sébastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either

```
AND NOT LOWER(hit.eventInfo.eventCategory) in ("login", "unknown", "registration", "login", "start", "null")
```

or

```
AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.eventInfo.eventCategory, r"(?i)^(login|unknown|registration|login|start|null)$")
```

Your query in question looks like quite truncated, so obviously just adding above will not work, so I would guess you wanted something like below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitNumber,
  visitStartTime,
  DATE,
  totals.visits,
  totals.hits,
  totals.pageviews,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  hit.hitNumber,
  hit.page.pagePath,
  hit.page.hostname,
  hit.page.pageTitle,
  hit.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  hit.eventInfo.eventAction,
  hit.eventInfo.eventLabel,
  cd.index,
  cd.value
FROM `bqdatasetnumber.ga_sessions_*` a,
UNNEST(hits) hit,
UNNEST(a.customDimensions) cd 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20130905' AND '20130911'
AND cd.value != "null"
AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.eventInfo.eventCategory, r"(?i)^(login|unknown|registration|login|start|null)$")
AND hit.eventInfo.eventAction != "start"
```

Not sure about source for cd, so guessed it is reference to customDimensions in root rather than in hits.  but it could be in hits :o)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail that was exactly what i was looking for. By the way, I appreciated a lot the book Learning Google BigQuery: A beginner's guide to mining massive datasets through interactive analysis in which your contribution are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.eventInfo.eventCategory, r"^Unknown|registration|login|start$") != true
```

You can find the documentation for the REGEXP_CONTAINS function [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains).

- The "Or" operand is "|"
- ^ and $, mean the value should be an exact match for the expression.
- nulls will be omitted as well.

Comment: Thanks ch_mike . Sorry for my late reply